# Permutations of polynomials

Tags: finite-groups, permutations

Is there an equation in $x$, $y$ and $z$ where there are exactly $2$ permutations in the variables that give fundamentally different polynomials? For example:

$$x+y+z$$ gives only one permutation
$$x+y+z^2$$ gives 3 permutations (we basically get to pick which variable replaces $z$)
$$x+y^2+z^3$$ gives 6 permutations (essentially $S_3$).

I've read that there is one for each factor of $3!$, but I don't see one for $2$. The examples above cover the obvious cases: all the same, two the same and all different. So is there an example with 2 permutations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try... 
$$x y^2 + y z^2 + z x^2$$

Comment: Got it, thanks. That's not an obvious polynomial to try.